# Security setup for multi-tenant with schemas in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, security, multi-tenant

I have a app than need separate schemas for each customer (financial data). Each tenant is a "company". From inside the company, can't access other companies in the same db server.

The db user must allow anything inside the schema, including perform db migrations. Actual end-user security is made by the app logic.

So this is what I have (TEMPLATE is replace by the company normalized name):

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS TEMPLATE CASCADE;

CREATE ROLE TEMPLATE
WITH
NOSUPERUSER
NOCREATEDB
NOCREATEROLE
INHERIT
CONNECTION LIMIT -1;

CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION TEMPLATE;

SELECT set_schema('TEMPLATE');
-- rest of db creation...
```

Is this enough?